# PayloadTooLargeError: too many parameters in body-parser

Tags: node.js, typescript, body-parser

i got PayloadTooLargeError then i used `bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 1000000})` to resolve it but since i am using typescript it is giving error for parameterLimit in VS code saying

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'parameterLimit' does not exist in type '{ inflate?: boolean; limit?: any; type?: any; verify?: (req: Request, res: Response, buf: Buffer,...'.

i checked the source code https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/body-parser/index.d.ts#L41, it is there. 
i am not getting how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging, I found out I was using a very old version of `index.d.ts` of `body-parser`.

I updated it to a more recent version and it works correctly now.